# How to P/Invoke when pointers are involved

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

In an attempt to learn to use PInvoke in C#, I'm a little unsure how to handle various cases with pointers involving simple value types.

I'm importing the following two functions from an unmanaged DLL:

```
public int USB4_Initialize(short* device);
public int USB4_GetCount(short device, short encoder, unsigned long* value);
```

The first function uses the pointer as an input, the second as an output. Their usage is fairly simple in C++:

```
// Pointer as an input
short device = 0; // Always using device 0.
USB4_Initialize(&device);

// Pointer as an output
unsigned long count;
USB4_GetCount(0,0,&count); // count is output
```

My first attempt in C# results in the following P/Invokes:

```
[DllImport("USB4.dll")]
public static extern int USB4_Initialize(IntPtr deviceCount); //short*

[DllImport("USB4.dll")]
public static extern int USB4_GetCount(short deviceNumber, short encoder, IntPtr value); //ulong*
```

**How do I use these functions in C# in the same way as the C++ code above?** Is there a better way to declare these types, perhaps using `MarshalAs`?

Comment: Hey, USB 4 already? I'm still waiting for 3.0

Comment: I wish. It has nothing to do with USB4. This is just a USB device the company has for connecting to an encoder, and since it's the 4th revision of their product, they stupidly named the product USB4.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the pointer is to a single primitive type and not an array, use ref / out to describe the parameter

```
[DllImport("USB4.dll")]
public static extern int USB4_Initialize(ref short deviceCount);

[DllImport("USB4.dll")]
public static extern int USB4_GetCount(short deviceNumber, short encoder, ref uint32 value)
```

In these examples out is probably more appropriate but either will work.

Comment: So in GetCount() I can use out instead of ref?

Comment: I see, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks.

Comment: Yep was gonna say the same thing except to have out in the USB4_GetCount definition

Answer (score 1):

The .NET runtime can do a lot of that conversion (referred to as "marshaling") for you. While an explicit IntPtr will always do EXACTLY what you tell it to, you can likely substitute the `ref` keyword for a pointer like that.

```
[DllImport("USB4.dll")]
public static extern int USB4_Initialize(ref short deviceCount); //short*

[DllImport("USB4.dll")]
public static extern int USB4_GetCount(short deviceNumber, short encoder, ref short value); //ulong*
```

You can then call them like this:

```
short count = 0;

USB4_Initialize(ref count);

// use the count variable now.
```