# How to reduce the cost of COM Interop / accessing?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, assembly, unmanaged

There's an alternative to P/Invoke when programming in Visual C++, using the [DllImport attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739.aspx). According to [Performance Considerations for Interop (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky8kkddw.aspx)
, I should try to reduce usage, to avoid the performance hit (emphasis mine):

> ### P/Invoke vs. C++ Interop
>
> For .NET languages, such as Visual Basic and C#, the prescribed method
> for interoperating with native components is P/Invoke. Because
> P/Invoke is supported by the .NET Framework, Visual C++ supports it as
> well, but Visual C++ also provides its own interoperability support,
> which is referred to as C++ Interop. C++ Interop is preferred over
> P/Invoke because P/Invoke is not type-safe. As a result, errors are
> primarily reported at run time, but **C++ Interop also has performance
> advantages over P/Invoke**.

So, my question is when I do need to access low level code, hardware or perform high performance calculations (which could still be possible from managed)? If i need higher(est!) performance, I could use some C++/CLI or Visual C++.
That is perfect! The only problem is I know almost nothing about C, C++, or Visual C++. So I thought if I need to learn (at least around the implementations I am going to use), why not step on the pedal all the way down right through to the metal, meaning to assembly.

So there is the question what assembler code would be possible to interact with,
if the target is mostly x64 code or actually AnyCpu could be good too.
The only problem I care about is performance in general use of unmanaged tasks.

What versions of assembly language are compatible with .NET? What I would like to choose is the fastest one. FASM/YASM/NASM?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem? Is it caused by the P/Invoke or interop overhead? Unless you can answer "yes" to both questions, this is not what you should be worrying about.     Balance is everything. Usually, "easiest to program" is the winner.

Comment: @Ben i am intending to pass all the "daily" usage of `unmanage` code to a separated dll , and interact as with generic all purpose unmanaged helper DLL

Comment: It sounds like you are planning a project from scratch. Or do you have an existing project with C++ components you need to interact with?

Comment: @Ben no not at all ..have nothing yet , and yes from scratch. and as i have said, i prefer lower than c++.

Comment: Assembly code is suppose to be obsolete.  The optimizing compilers and the high speed microprocessors make it unnecessary.   I would only go to assembly language if you have a performance issue.  First write code in higher level language and then do some bench testing before actually writing the assembly language program. Minimize where you use the assembly language based on the tests.  It is better to do a good job of designing the code than to have to use assembly language to compensate for poorly written code.

Comment: If it's a new project I recommend using something you already have some experience with, and become expert in that. C# can do almost everything you will want. And those other things? Perhaps you will not need them. Perhaps performance is not a problem. Why not wait until you discover if it is?

Comment: [Performance differences between P/Invoke and C++ Wrappers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433334/performance-differences-between-p-invoke-and-c-wrappers)